# Получить id каждой записи

Tags: symfony, php, symfony2

```
$posts = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('TestBundle:Materials')->findAll();

foreach($posts as $midcount) {
            $posts['id'];
        }
        echo $midcount;
```

как правильно будет ?
Notice: Undefined index: id

Answer (score 1):

1. Вы перебираете `$posts`, соответственно для получения id записей обращаться нужно к `$midcount`. [Cтруктура foreach](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php)
2. Метод репозитория `findAll` [возвращает массив объектов](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.0/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html#_findAll).

Для вашего случая будет примерно так:

```
$posts = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('TestBundle:Materials')->findAll();

foreach($posts as $post) {
    echo $post->getId();
}
```

В целом нужно было задавать вопрос о том, как работает foreach, а не про Doctrine.